# Why does calling pop on an empty array set the length to 0?

Tags: javascript

Given that the length of the array was already set to 0, why does `pop` set it to zero again?

Here are the first three steps of [the ECMAScript 2023 spec for `pop`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.pop):

```
1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
2. Let len be ? LengthOfArrayLike(O).
3. If len = 0, then
    a. Perform ? Set(O, "length", +0, true).
    b. Return undefined.
```

This seems redundant to me, which leads me to believe that I'm not understanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Elsewhere in the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.concat) the `length` property is re-set to zero (e.g. `concat`), and the reasoning is documented there:

> The explicit setting of the "`length`" property in step 6 is necessary to ensure that its value is correct in situations where the trailing elements of the result Array are not present.

[...and...](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.slice)

> The explicit setting of the "`length`" property of the result `Array` in step 15 was necessary in previous editions of ECMAScript to ensure that its length was correct in situations where the trailing elements of the result `Array` were not present. Setting "`length`" became unnecessary starting in ES2015 when the result `Array` was initialized to its proper length rather than an empty `Array` but is carried forward to preserve backward compatibility.

Note how in `pop` the `len` value comes from [`LengthOfArrayLike`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-lengthofarraylike) which does more than just simply get the "`length`" property value: it coerces the type and restricts the range to integers.

...so the only situation in which it matters is if you have an *almost* `Array`-like object with a `length` property that returns a non-`number` value if empty:

```js
let notArray = { length: "apples" };
console.log(notArray);
Array.prototype.pop.bind(notArray)();
console.log(notArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in both instances, the array was empty which always means the length is 0.

Pop on such an array of course will do nothing to increase the length, and so it remains 0.

It started at 0 for length. Pop will return nothing but it doesn’t leave the array undefined. Instead the array remains length 0.